# How to concat df with for loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have four df with name and count.values() like this:

```
topInv.Inv2.value_counts()
```

```
    Tiger Global Management    20
 Accel                      18
 Sequoia Capital            17
 General Catalyst           15
 Insight Partners           14
                            ..
 AME Cloud Ventures          1
 Eleation Capital            1
 Alven Capital               1
 CJ ENM                      1
 True                        1
  
Name: Inv2, Length: 601, dtype: int64
```

To move more easily and learn some 'for loops' I created a list:

```
d = {} # Dictionary
for i in list(range(2,6,1)):
    d['c'+str(i)]=pd.DataFrame(topInv.iloc[:,[i]].value_counts()) # dictionary with c2 to c5
    
antonio = []
for i in list(range(2,6,1)): # list extracted from dict
    pl = d['c'+str(i)]
    antonio.append([pl])
```

Now, all I need to do is a concat to sum respective value counts beacuse some dataframes can have the same values, for example 'Accel'.

Actually I did this way

```
c1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([antonio[0], antonio[1], antonio[2], antonio[3]]))
```

But:

1. I didn't use a for loop so, in case there are more columns to concatenate I'm not able to do.
2. I wasn't able to count them. I tried with .sum() but I'm not sure it was right.

What I really want to know is how to say to Python 'add the next "i" after comma", I explain better with an example code:

```
# imagine i want to concatenate 4 df, one column each

asd = [a,b,c,d] 
for i in list(range(0,4,1)): # list extracted from dict
    app = pd.concat([asd[i])
    print(app)
```

By lauching this code I will obtain app created only with d (the last one of iterative i) instead of asd = pd.concat([a,b,c,d]).

Thanks

Edit 1:
This is what I want to achieve:

```
    investor    count
0   Sequoia Capital China   30
1   Andreessen Horowitz 29
2   Accel   28
3   Insight Partners    23
4   Sequoia Capital 17
... ... ...
1733    Redpoint Ventures   1
1734    Redpoint e.ventures 1
1735    SDIC CMC Investment Management  1
1736    Softbank Group  1
1737    Spark Capital   1  
  
1738 rows × 2 columns
```

Every dataframe or list has 2 column: investor and value count. In this example every dataframe was appended after the last one. With the last code above I will obtain only the last df (of list) as result and not a concatenation.

Comment: you don't want to use `pd.concat` inside a `for` loop. Build up your list of dataframes in side your loop, and call `pd.concat` only once after that's done. You also don't need to wrap `pd.concat` inside `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: So you know how to use `pd.concat` with a list of frames or Series.  Can't you just a make a new list with the desired columns?

Comment: I think the OP just needs to call `topInv.value_counts()` and the select out the desired columns. I suspect `concat` and for loops aren't necessary anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You don't really show us your data or the final product you're trying to achieve. As such, this isn't a very good Stack Overflow question.

However, I think you can achieve what I assume you want with what I assume you have without using `pd.concat` or `for` loops.

If you find yourself looping with pandas dataframe, stop and search for a vectorized way. There almost always is a way to avoid loops.

Try this:

```py
topInv[:, [2:6]].value_counts().rename(columns=lambda col: "c" + col)
```